# Get distances using ST_Distance_Sphere & ST_GeomFromText

Tags: postgresql, distance, postgis

I am trying to use postgis to calculate distances between points. I have the (from to coordinates) as Lat & Long in a table. I researched some code and it looks like this:

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(
(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || distance.sfg_long || ' ' ||  distance.sfg_lat || ')',4326)), 
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || distance.plg_long || ' ' || distance.plg_lat || ')',4326))
FROM distance;
```

I get this message:

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT(SF" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
SQL state: XX000
```

All I want to do is get the distance and It looks like other people used a similar approach and it worked for them.

Any clues what is going on?

Comment: Provide some sample data from this table. I'd dare to say that it does not contain numeric values in the fields you're using to build the geometry.

Comment: Jim Jones, that you for pointing that out. I double check the data types and yes, they weren't numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have either a typo in your query, or an invalid value in your longitude column. Going by the error message, could it be that one of the values in sfg_long is text starting with "SF"?

Sharing your table design and some sample records would help us to help you. I am going to assume your columns are text.

I would try something like the following. The [ST_POINT](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) syntax is clearer.

```
SELECT ST_Distancesphere(
   st_setsrid(st_point(distance.sfg_long::numeric,distance.sfg_lat::numeric),4326),
   st_setsrid(st_point(distance.plg_long::numeric,distance.plg_lat::numeric),4326)
) FROM distance
    -- st_distance_sphere is deprecated since 2.2.0
```

Comment: after reading your messages I went back and realize I had text values instead of numeric values. I created a new table with numeric values and got my answer right away.